# Expectation of Minimum Value of 4 Distinct Integers from the Set $ \left\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 47, 48 \right\}$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, expectation

Suppose I choose $4$ distinct integers from the set $\{1,2,3,...,47,48\}$. What would be the expectation of the minimum of the four numbers (say $X$).

My attempt: Using tail sum formula we get:

$P(X\geq1)+...+P(X\geq45) = \frac{48C4}{48C4}+\frac{47C4}{48C4}+...+\frac{4C4}{48C4}.$

Where can I go from here?

P.S. is there a way to approach this question from a more intuitive sense?

Comment: You have a common denominator. For the numerator, look up the hockey-stick formula.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $\binom{47}{3}$ subsets with a minimum of $1$ since such a set must contain $3$ of the $47$ larger numbers in the set?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig it's the probability $X\geq1$ not $X=1$

Comment: I don't know what the "hockey-stick formula" is but it seems to be the fad nowadays to make up silly names for everything, so I guess it's a name for the formula $$\sum_{n=0}^{48}\binom n4=\binom{49}5.$$

Comment: @bof's sum is correct: both sides give 1,906,884, but that is larger than ${48 \choose 4},$ so I don't see a probability on the horizon.

Comment: @BruceET We're not looking for a probability, we're looking for an expectation. $\binom{49}5/\binom{48}4=\frac{49}5=9.8$ seems reasonable for the expected value of the smallest of $4$ numbers drawn without replacement from $\{1,\dots,48\}.$

Comment: @bof: Sorry, you're right. Up too late. Misread the problem. Simulation in R: `mean(replicate(10^6,  min(sample(1:48,4))))` returns 9.792629, where one can expect 2 or 3 significant digits of accuracy.

Comment: On intuition: A continuous version of this is to sample 4 values from UNIF(0,1). In this case 'on average' the 4 points tend divide the unit interval into five intervals of equal length. Thus the avg min of 4 is at $1/5 = 0.2.$ Discrete versions are not so transparent, but correct answ. $49/5$ is not grossly different from $48/5.$ I don't see an intuitive path to the exactly correct answer. // A somewhat similar problem is the 'German tank problem' in which one tries to use the max observation to est pop total. You can google that. And BTW, Wikipedia has a nice article on 'hockey stick'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the familiar [combinatorial identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)
$$\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ik$$
with $k=4$ and $n=48,$ the expectation is
$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{48}P(X\ge i)=\sum_{i=0}^{47}P(X\gt i)=\sum_{i=0}^{47}\frac{\binom{48-i}4}{\binom{48}4}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{48}\binom i4}{\binom{48}4}=\frac{\binom{49}5}{\binom{48}4}=\frac{49}5=9.8$$

Answer (score 1):

Defining $ X $ as the minimum value of the chosen 4 numbers.

By definifion:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{45} \mathbb{P} \left( X = i \right) i $$

The probability $ \mathbb{P} \left( X = i \right) $ is choosing the number $ i $ and counting the number of combinations of choosing 3 other values higher than $ i $ divided by the number of combinations to have 4 numbers out of 48:

$$ \mathbb{P} \left( X = i \right) = \frac{ \binom{48 - i}{3} }{ \binom{48}{4} } $$

This yields:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{45} \mathbb{P} \left( X = i \right) i = \sum_{i = 1}^{45} \frac{ \binom{48 - i}{3} }{ \binom{48}{4} } i = 9.8 $$

The above is easy to evaluate using MATLAB:

```
% Monte Carlo Simulation:
numTrials = 5e6;

vX = zeros([numTrials, 1]);

for ii = 1:numTrials
    vX(ii) = min(randperm(48, 4));
end

mean(vX)

% Analytic Simulation

vX = [1:48].';
vP = zeros([48, 1]); %<! Probability of X
denVal = nchoosek(48, 4); %<! Number of combinatirons of 4 values out of 48

for ii = 1:45
    numVal = nchoosek(48 - ii, 3);
    vP(ii) = numVal / denVal;
end


sum(vP .* vX)
```